# How to get the ckeditor browse server window with ckfinder from an external button?

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

ckeditor has this beautiful demo of ckfinder: http://cksource.com/ckfinder/demo#ckeditor.

I dont need the entire editor, I only need a button that will open the ckfinder window and let me use only this specefic plugin.

Is it possible ? How can I do that ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://cksource.com/ckfinder/demo#forms If yes, then download CKFinder and check _samples/popup.html

Comment: This is a payed solution, I'm looking for a free one :-)

Comment: Then I have no idea what do you ask about, because you just asked how to open the CKFinder window.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see that it was a payed feature before...
I did find a free version of this plug-in here: [http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/demos/standalone]

Comment: Just to make things clear: it's a different application that has nothing to do with CKFinder.

Comment: You are correct. My appologies for the mistake.